# Accessing values from nested JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, xml, xslt

I am a bit confused in the nested structure of JSON. I am trying to do ng-repeat for a JSON key facing few error.

I am converting XSL to JSON which is successfully happening. Now I wan to access that JSON to edit fields.

**My JSON after converting:-**

```
{
  "stylesheet": {
    "attribute-set": [
      {
        "attribute": {
          "_name": "text-align",
          "__prefix": "xsl",
          "__text": "center"
        },
        "_name": "__frontmatter",
        "__prefix": "xsl"
      },
      {
        "attribute": [
          {
            "_name": "space-before",
            "__prefix": "xsl",
            "__text": "80mm"
          },
          {
            "_name": "space-before.conditionality",
            "__prefix": "xsl",
            "__text": "retain"
          },
          {
            "_name": "font-size",
            "__prefix": "xsl",
            "__text": "22pt"
          },
          {
            "_name": "font-weight",
            "__prefix": "xsl",
            "__text": "bold"
          },
          {
            "_name": "line-height",
            "__prefix": "xsl",
            "__text": "140%"
          }
        ],
        "_name": "__frontmatter__title",
        "_use-attribute-sets": "common.title",
        "__prefix": "xsl"
      },
      {
        "attribute": [
          {
            "_name": "font-size",
            "__prefix": "xsl",
            "__text": "18pt"
          },
          {
            "_name": "font-weight",
            "__prefix": "xsl",
            "__text": "bold"
          },
          {
            "_name": "line-height",
            "__prefix": "xsl",
            "__text": "140%"
          }
        ],
        "_name": "__frontmatter__subtitle",
        "_use-attribute-sets": "common.title",
        "__prefix": "xsl"
      },
      {
        "attribute": [
          {
            "_name": "space-before",
            "__prefix": "xsl",
            "__text": "36pt"
          },
          {
            "_name": "font-size",
            "__prefix": "xsl",
            "__text": "11pt"
          },
          {
            "_name": "font-weight",
            "__prefix": "xsl",
            "__text": "bold"
          },
          {
            "_name": "line-height",
            "__prefix": "xsl",
            "__text": "normal"
          }
        ],
        "_name": "__frontmatter__owner",
        "_use-attribute-sets": "common.title",
        "__prefix": "xsl"
      }
    ],
    "_xmlns:xsl": "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform",
    "_xmlns:fo": "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format",
    "_version": "2.0",
    "__prefix": "xsl"
  }
}
```

I want to access this portion :-

```
"attribute": {
    "_name": "text-align",
      "__prefix": "xsl",
      "__text": "center"
}
```

*ng-repeat* textbox by reading key `_name`with showing label ie; the value and input value from the textbox must change `__text` values.

**My controller:-**

```js
$scope.xml = '';
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'test.xsl',
  timeout: 10000,
  transformResponse: function(data) {
    //string -> XML document object
    $scope.xml = data;
  }
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  //console.dir(data);          
  $scope.x2js = new X2JS();
  $scope.xmlText = $scope.xml;
  $scope.jsonObj = $scope.x2js.xml_str2json($scope.xmlText);
  console.log($scope.jsonObj);
  angular.forEach($scope.jsonObj, function(value, key) {
    console.log(value.attribute-set); ** // here I am getting ReferenceError: set is not defined in console**
    angular.forEach(value.attribute, function(v, k) {
      console.log(v._name);
      console.log(v.__text);
    });
  });
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  $window.alert('didnt passed.');
});
```

**My HTML view:-**

```html
<form method="post" id="contactFrm" name="contactFrm">
  <div ng-repeat="attrs in jsonObj.attribute._name">
    <input type=" text " required=" " placeholder=" " value=" " name="values " class="txt " ng-model="spaceb " ng-repeat="(key, val) in attrs>
  </div>
</form>
```

*So how can I get `"_name"` as nested value to use ng-repeat in textfield ?*

Comment: Dot notation is not possible with invalid javascript variable names such as something with a hyphen which is a minus in JS:  `value.attribute-set` You can try `value["attribute-set"]`

Comment: @mplungjan ok , and how will can I access `"_name"` in each `attribute` to show in ng-repeat input in view ?

Comment: Its the same. `value["attribute-set"][0]["attribute"]["_name"]`

Comment: @NathanStockton I am only getting the value of first node value ie; only  `"_name": "text-align",`

Comment: Change the 0 :) you can use a for loop to iterate through them

Comment: @NathanStockton I tried using for loop , still not getting all the value. How will use the `_name`  in `ng-repeat` view?

Comment: Just reread your code. You will need 2 for loops - one for scanning through each attribute and then another to scan through each object within it. Its a bit hard on the phone I am using but I should get a minute tonight to get on a computer to write this up for you if you need